# Hallo , how can I convert a hexString to int . I have "F3A4" and i want to write a method or use Java_API to get the int. How code I do it please?

Tags: java

public static void main(String[] args) {

int a;
String b= "F22D";
a
//I want to have the int of "F22D". How could I do it please?

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function

```
String b="F22D";
int num=Integer.parseInt(b,16);

//this returns an int value.
```